# Expand specific GroupBy's and pagination

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that filters and orders a list of records (from a database) by dynamic properties and skips/takes according to current pagination-settings the appropriate amount of records.

This all works fine. Now I want to group the records (by dynamic keys again) and be able to expand the groups each individually (on users choice). Additionally I need this to work with the pagination.

So for example I have a list of say 100 records `new { Name = ..., Category = ..., Prop1 = ..., Prop2 = ..., }` which are already filtered and ordered (from the total set of whatever records). Lets assume we got 10 different categories (ranging from 1 to 10) and the current pagination is set to 10 items starting at 0.

Now I want these records grouped by their `Category` and lets say the groups where `Category == 5` (items matching this 3) and `Category == 8` (items matching this 10) expanded, the rest collapsed.

What should be returned

```
Group {Category == 1)
Group {Category == 2)
Group {Category == 3)
Group {Category == 4)
Group {Category == 5)
    {
        { Name, Category, Prop1, Prop2, ... }
        { Name, Category, Prop1, Prop2, ... }
        { Name, Category, Prop1, Prop2, ... }
    }
Group {Category == 6)
Group {Category == 7)
Group {Category == 8)
    {
        { Name, Category, Prop1, Prop2, ... }
    }
```

So the returned amount of 'entries' is 10. Collapsed categories count for 1 entry each and expanded categories count for the items they hold. The last expanded category got 'cut down' because the items would exceed the total requested amount of entries (10).

Ideally this is all based on `IQueryable` so that only the requested items get pulled from the database.

I did look into `GroupBy` and `GroupJoin`, but I am not sure on how to limit the items in those groupings by the requested record-count.

Comment: Limiting the records retrieved from the DB becomes tricky as they are now effectively variable, not constant, ie they vary on the amount of items in the group. What you might find easier to do is page on the outer set - the group records & load the sub items on demand.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Simon.  I would think that paging just on the outer set would be simpler as well as more usable.  For instance, what happens in your example if Category 8 has more than one item?  Would you break the category up over multiple pages?  If so, how would the user know that that group actually has more items in it?  Another option would be to flatten the list so that there is no grouping, and then just display the category information for each row.

Comment: How would I go about to flatten the list only for specific groups?